# How to set a bg colour in html table cell for all specifc cases

Tags: html, css, perl

I want an `bgcolour` to be `red` for all `name=arun` and `phone_no=null` , I am running this html in perl to send an email output of sql query. Here the sql data is dynamic.

Here is the snippet of the code :

```
$STYLE=<<STYLE;
    <style type="text/css">
    .mytable { background-color:#E0E0E0;border: 1px solid blue;border-collapse: collapse; }
    .mytable th { background-color:#666600;color:white;font-size: 100%; }
    .mytable td { padding:3px;border:1px solid #0066FF; }
    </style>
    push(@HTML,"<table class=\"myTable\" border=1>\12<tr bgcolor=708090><th>name</th><th>college</th><th>phone_no</th></tr>");
    $retCode=executeSQL("select name,college,phone_no from source_table");
    if($retCode) {
        push(@HTML,"<tr><td">&nbsp;</td><td"></td><td"></td><td">");
        push(@HTML,"<td"></td><td></td></tr>\12");
    }
    push(@HTML,"</table>\12\12");
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain. Use [a template language](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Alloy/lib/Template/Alloy.pod) for HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use of quotes in the code.